# JavaScript constructor and namespace in object literal style

Tags: javascript, object-oriented, prototypal-class-design

Is this a good way to create a class with a constructor and namespace in object literal style?

```
// root namespace
var myApp = myApp || {};

// sub namespace
myApp.model = {
    // Constructor
    Person: function (name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
};


myApp.model.Person.prototype = {
    sayName: function () {
        alert(this.name);
    },
    sayHi: function () {
        alert("Hi, " + this.name);
    }
};

var p1 = new myApp.model.Person("CK");
p1.sayName();
p1.sayHi();
```

JSHint shows no error and the full source code is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/cklee75/vj4ujz0L/2/).

Comment: I may be incorrect, but wouldn't your `myApp.model.Person.prototype` only add those functions to the `Person` objects that are a part of your `myApp.model`, and not all `Person` objects? If that is intended, that's fine. I could just see that becoming an issue later on. Do you have a separate `Person` object?

Comment: I am from Java background. I want to make `myApp.model` as my package, the fully qualified class name I want to make is `myApp.model.Person`. This class shall have a constructor that take String `name` as parameter, and have 2 methods `sayName` and `sayHi`. It is simple to be achieved in Java, but I am not sure how to make it right  in Javascript.

Comment: @krillgar, there is no other `Person` object. Why it could be an issue if I define my qualified class name as `myApp.model.Person`?

Comment: Because if you apply changes to the prototype of an instance of a JavaScript object, they only apply to that instance. To apply those two functions to EVERY instance of a `Person` object, you need to assign them to the root `Person` object definition. I'm not sure if this would count as an instance. Most likely, it'd be only to the `Person` objects that belong to `myApp.model` objects. So if you have `Person` somewhere else, then those objects won't have those functions on them.

Comment: @krillgar: if you make a 2nd instance of  myApp.model.Person (with different constructor arg), it'll work ok: http://jsfiddle.net/vj4ujz0L/3/

Comment: So that's like I said where it will work for the `Person` on anything that derives from `myApp.model`. Since he doesn't have a stand-alone `Person` object, he'll be fine. But if anyone else coming by see this, they should be wary of that fact.

Comment: @krillgar You needn't be concerned. JavaScript doesn't care where the `Person` constructor is stored, whether it's `myApp.model.Person` or anywhere else. All `Person` instances which share that constructor will have access to the functions attached to the constructor's `prototype`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks good to me. From a once over;

- Consider using `'use strict'`
- You cannot have 'private' functions or properties, that should be fine
- Naming is fine. As I personally dislike namespaces I would probably go for a 1 character namespace for `myApp`.
- Indenting is fine
- 0 comments, you might want to consider one-liner comments separating the different sections of your code.
- Somewhat to krillgar's point, `instanceof` checks will have to check against `myApp.model.Person` with your approach, this should be fine as well

All in all, JavaScript is not Java. I would not go so far as to say that namespaces are not idiomatic, but I would invite you read [this](http://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/).

Comment: If the listed code is under Person.js file, I would like to add another class `myApp.model.Facility` at another Facility.js file. How should I define the sub namespace block? This may worth for another question, but hope you can answer as well.

Comment: @CK by combining your first line with my answer, ie `myApp.model = myApp.model || {};` followed by `myApp.model.Person = /*...*/` rather than `myApp.model = { Person /*...*/`

Comment: I disagree re: comments - comments should only be added to code that is hard to understand without the comment. Assuming that this code will be read by people who know javascript, no comments are needed in this code.

Comment: @TV'sFrank It's an opinion, I would invite you to look at CK Lee's answer, the comments make it more readable in my mind.

Comment: @CKLee You should look up "javascript module pattern". You'll find a pattern for isolating your new variables from the global namespace, and within that context you can safely alias your namespaces to something convenient like this: `var Person = myApp.model.Person`.

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest splitting the addition of the methods as follows:

```
myApp.model.Person.prototype.sayName = function () {
    alert(this.name);
};

myApp.model.Person.prototype.sayHi = function () {
    alert("Hi, " + this.name);
};
```

This way you can define additional methods in different places (if needed), as you're not replacing the entire prototype in one go.

Comment: In Java, normally we define all methods under `public class Person { ... }` block in a same file. Should it be good to put all related methods in the same place in Javascript as well?

Comment: Yes, it would be normal to group them together for ease of maintenance, but nothing actually stopping you in the language from putting them wherever you want

Comment: I might be wrong, but I don't understand how the OP's solution doesn't allow you to later on add extra functions to the prototype (something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/vj4ujz0L/6/)

Comment: ShivanDragon is right. But I'd still recommend following James Thorpe's advice and adding your new methods to the prototype that's already there, since that approach works nicely with inheritance models. Oh, and please never add methods to a single prototype at multiple different places (unless your project is very small or you have a very clear set of conventions to which everyone agrees).

Comment: @ShivanDragon Yes, you can add them to the prototype, so long as you do so after you've already done the original assignment.  If you add each method individually, it can make refactoring easier as you don't need to ensure they're added after the initial assignment

Answer (score 1):

Based on comment from konijin, here is the updated version

```
// root namespace
var myApp = myApp || {};

// sub namespace
myApp.model = myApp.model || {};

// constructor
myApp.model.Person = function (name) {
    this.name = name;
}

myApp.model.Person.prototype = {
    sayName: function () {
        alert(this.name);
    },
    sayHi: function () {
        alert("Hi, " + this.name);
    }
};

var p1 = new myApp.model.Person("CK");
p1.sayName();
p1.sayHi();

alert(p1 instanceof myApp.model.Person); // true
alert(p1 instanceof Object); // true
alert(p1 instanceof Person); // Uncaught ReferenceError: Person is not defined
```

http://jsfiddle.net/cklee75/1d6jgx4k/3/

Answer (score 1):

When you assign an object to a prototype it changes the prototypal inheritance of that object. The prototype of the object will no longer have the original constructor function and it will point to `Object` instead!

This affects your code, as it is evidenced by adding the following line:

```
console.log(p1.constructor === Object); // returns: true
```

Two ways to correct this:

**A.** Assign the functions directly. Don't wrap them in an object. That would look like this:

```
myApp.model.Person.prototype.sayName = function(){
   alert(this.name);
};

myApp.model.Person.prototype.sayHi = function(){
    alert("Hi, " + this.name);
};
```

**B.** Reassign the constructor to your object. You can do that by adding a line of code into your object, like this:

```
myApp.model.Person.prototype = {
    constructor: myApp.model.Person, //  <========
    sayName: function () {
        alert(this.name);
    },
    sayHi: function () {
        alert("Hi, " + this.name);
    }
};
```

Which is the same as this:

```
myApp.model.Person.prototype.constructor = myApp.model.Person;
```

It's worth noting that restoring the constructor in this manner creates a property with `enumerable` set to `true`. Native constructors are not enumerable by default. So if you're using ES5, this might be the preferred way to restore the constructor:

```
Object.defineProperty(myApp.model.Person.prototype, 'constructor', {
enumerable: false,
value: myApp.model.Person
});
```

More reading on this: http://javascript.info/tutorial/constructor